# Ignore null Tag during marshiling xml using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

is there an option in JAX ignore null value of element from marshaling ,
so in case i have java object customer and the address is null , during marshaling how can i write the xml with out the address tag
(i don;t want to use EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) )

Code Example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Customer")
public class Customer
{
    @XmlElement(name = "name")  
    String name = null;
    @XmlElement(name = "address")   
    String address = null;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

in case address is null i expect not to have the address tag in the xml.

Thanks

Comment: i don;t want default value , i want that in the generated xml the tag address is not appear

Comment: can i determine the name of the xml TAG in run time as input from the user and not write it like @XmlElement(name = "name")

Answer (score 1):

> in case address is `null` i expect not to have the `address` tag in the xml

This happens by default.